# Select and count a joined table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, doctrine-orm

**Hello,**

I make a website where people can buy tickets for a show, I need to know how many tickets are sold depending of a variable date.

I have 2 tables:

1) Reservation table which contain the reservation date;
2) Tickets table which is linked to my reservation table.

Here is my code:

```
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('a');
                $qb->select('a');
                $qb->where('a.dateReservation = :dateReservation');
                $qb->setParameter('dateReservation',$date);
                $qb->leftJoin('a.ticket', 't');
                $qb->addSelect('COUNT(t)');
```

If anyone knows how to get the joined tickets from reservation($date) and count it, it would be awesome ! (DQL request prefered )

[DataBase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOzpg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the SQL code you want, I don't know DQL

```
SELECT COUNT *
FROM Ticket INNER JOIN Reservation
ON Ticket.reservation_id = Reservation.id
WHERE DATE = $date
```

and of course the variable of your function is $date here

Answer (score 0):

See the below sql query for sold ticket. I think this will help you

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as sold_tickets
FROM reservations r left join tickets t
ON t.reservation_id = r.id WHERE date(r.date) = '2016-06-30'
```

Comment: Men I just note that I can access of all tickets propertys except the reservation_Id one . 

I don't know why , I don't know what to do !

Comment: can you share what is the primary key and foreign key of table, also see the below code. I think you need to put this                                                                                                   SELECT COUNT(*) as sold_tickets
FROM reservations r , tickets t WHERE t.reservation_id = r.id and date(r.date) = '2016-06-30'

Comment: Yes I took a screen shot : 

http://www.noelshack.com/2016-26-1467320183-zefz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close.  It's not clear exactly what problem you're hitting, but I'm going to guess that you're not getting the results you expect.

This is probably because you're using an aggregate function (`COUNT(t)`) without doing a group by.

Try adding: `$qb->groupBy('a');`

If that doesn't do what you want, please update your question to be more clear about what issue you're having.

Comment: Thanks but after 4 H seaching I note that  I can access of all tickets propertys except the reservation_Id one . I don't know why , I don't know what to do !

Comment: What does reservation_id have to do with your question?  Please try to be more clear.  It seems like you're confused about the foreign key ticket.reservation_id.  You can't access that through your entity.  Instead, you can do something like `$ticket->getReservation()->getId()`.  While reservation_id exists in the database, it does *not* exist in your entity.

Comment: Like you see bellow I need ticket.reservation_id to compare with my reservation.id but as I told you, ticket.reservation_id is the only column I can't reach and I still don't know why

Comment: You need to ask your question better.  Why do you need that column, in what context, for what purpose?  How are you trying to get it?  What result were you expecting, and what result did you get?  The short answer is that the foreign key column is not visible from your entity.  Your Ticket entity doesn't **have** a reservation_id, it has a Reservation entity.

Comment: Also, ignore the other answers here.  They're talking about SQL.  You're dealing with a DQL query here, which is a different beast.

Comment: I understand your schema, what I don't understand is the problem.  Did you add the groupBy that I suggested, and look at those results?  If you still need an answer, you need to update your question with more detail (code), and ask a clear, specific, question.

Comment: If you've been stuck on this for two days, you can improve your question.  Even if I wanted to, I couldn't write code for you to try because I still don't understand your problem  Fix your question.